# definition of the Fréchet derivative: why assume it is a bounded linear map?

Tags: analysis, frechet-derivative

Definition (in our lecture): Let $X,Y$ be normed vector spaces and $f:U \to Y$ with $U \subset X$ open. Then $f$ is called Fréchet-differentiable in $x_0 \in U$ if there exists a linear map $A:X \to Y$ such that

$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{||f(x)-f(x_0)-A(x-x_0)||_Y}{||x-x_0||_X}=0.$$

In all books I looked into there is additionally required that $A$ is continuous. Is this assumption necessary?

Comment: I think you need $A$ to be bounded, and linear maps on normed vector spaces are bounded iff continuous.

Comment: It is part of the definition. This is automatically satisfied for finite dimensional spaces.

Comment: @B.Goddard Yes, the assumption that $A$ is continuous is equivalent to $A$ is bounded but do we need this assumption or is this definition of our lecture a more general one?

Comment: @Bernard It's clear that in the finite dimensional case it doesn't matters since all linear operators are bounded. But why do we require this for the infinitedimensional setting?

Comment: Probably because many theorems in analysis (for differentiable manifolds, functional analysis) require $C^k$ functions  (I'm no analyst…)

Comment: Asking $A$ to be bounded/continuous ensures that $A(x-x_0)$ tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to $x_0$. So $f(x_0)+A(x-x_0)$ is a good first approximation of $f(x)$ for $x$ close to $x_0$

Comment: If we don't require continuity of the differential, the function $f$ itself might be discontinuous. In fact, if the differential is discontinuous, then it is also discontinuous at $0$. For the limit in the definition above to exist, the limit of the numerator must be $0$. And if the limit of $A(x-x_0)$ is not  $0$, the limit of $f(x)-f(x_0)$ can't be $0$ either, making $f$ discontinuous at $x_0$. This could possibly result in things like $C^n$ not being a superset of $C^{n+1}$ (a function could have discontinuous $n$-th derivative, which is then continuously differentiable).

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos   Oh this makes a lot of sense, thank you!